Comparing two populations mortality rates
I’m starting a report for open uni and am proposing to compare the mortality rates of cardiovascular disease between two countries. One is higher  than the other looking at the data and I’m going to try and explain the difference by looking at data from alcohol use, tobacco use, exercise and diet.  Can someone explain in layman’s terms what would be best to do? I don’t really want to get into explaining differences over time as that’s adding more complexity to it. So would comparing the  average over the time span be appropriate? Would a bar graph or line graph be better? Would looking at just one particular year be better?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
